# Check constraint after update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, foreign-keys, constraints

I wanna remove some constraint by query to update my field and add constraint again. I use "nocheck constraint" to disable and "check constraint" to drop and add. no check works but when I use check after update my field,it does not work.
How can I fix it?

Here is an example of what I do:

```
ALTER TABLE t NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_a]
UPDATE t SET b+=10;    --b depends on FK_a
ALTER TABLE t CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_a]
```

befor I use nocheck, I get an error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_a".

I except I get this error after use check and update query again, but update query works without any problem!

I use drop and add and got the same result. Why?

my table script is:

```
CREATE TABLE t(
[b] [smallint] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_a] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [b] ASC,
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE t WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_a] FOREIGN KEY([b])
REFERENCES [t] ([b])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE t CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_a]
```

Comment: Please provide table and constraint DDL.

Comment: I added it in my question:)

Comment: It is very possible that the reason that led you to "temporarily" remove the constraint was that you INSERT rows that make the table not satisfy it.  You afterwards try to re-create the constraint. You may NOT create a constraint on a table, if the contraint is not met! In this case: you cannot re-activate an FK if you have changed an FK field's value to one that does not exist in the FK's target field value-set.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis if it is true, why did not I get an error when I enable constraint again?

Comment: Please provide your entire query so we may see what's happening.

Comment: my entire query is example Query which wrote in question.